# possibility to debug user-extensions.js in selenium

Tags: debugging, selenium-rc

I have a webapp which is tested by selenium. Everything works well: writing tests in java, setting breakpoints in my webapp through firebug.

unfortunately I am not able to debug the user-extensions.js it self: After starting the java-test, two firefox windows are opened. One holds the webapp to test, the other one holds the data-flow which uses the user-extensions.

How can I debug the user-extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible. I made a workaround and switched the functions to my webapp to debug them there.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the browser you're using.  I've been able to debug user-extensions using Chrome.  In the control Window, you need to right-click and then view the window as a tab.  Once you do that, you can activate the developer tools for the control window, which will include the JavaScript debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It's possibile using the ***Venkman* debugger** (a separate Firefox extension) and **Firefox up until version *32***, and that's quite a **precious combination**.

With Firefox 33 and later, Venkman is broken by api changes, and the native debugger unluckily doesn't allow to debug xul based extensions.